# Is there a legal way to redistribute Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.11.0.dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, t4

I am writing a software that extends Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. The software is T4 text template based and I need to redistribute the T4 engine. How can I legally deploy the T4 engine?

Comment: What are the licensing and distribution terms for this library?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399733/how-to-deploy-t4-include-files-with-nuget-package

Comment: You might try looking at Mono/MonoDevelops T4 engine. I don't imagine it's compatible at an internal level, but they do the same thing (I use T4 a lot and have more problems with Microsoft's than Mono's heh)

Comment: Actually MonoDevelop is (for most of these scenarios) basically entirely compatible with VS T4. After all, they both use same interface definitions. We solved our alike requirement with MonoDevelop - had to alter some "include notations" but nothing major.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, T4 is not a redistributable component.